# 3D plot not showing

Tags: r, plotly, shiny

I have developed a shiny app. I wanted to plot a 3D scatter plot and render it into the shiny app.

The problem is when I run the app, the plot itself doesn't appear. Although the legend and plotly options appear in the plot area. If I click the snapshot option of plotly it does download the plot in png.

here is the code:

```
#ui.R
  actionButton('RUN', 'Run')
  plotlyOutput("plot3D")

#server.R
  output$plot3D <- renderPlotly({
     req(input$RUN)
     isolate({
     plot_ly(df, x = ~t1, y = ~t2, z = ~t3, type = "scatter3d", mode = 
     "markers") 
     })
 })
```

Any ideas why the plot is not showing in plot area?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/README.html#what-is-a-reprex) as asked by the R tag (hover over it). `df` is missing, for example, as well as the required library calls etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your package(s)? This seems to work:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
packageVersion("plotly")
# [1] ‘4.7.1.9000’
packageVersion("shiny")
# [1] ‘1.0.3’
ui <-  fluidPage(
  actionButton('RUN', 'Run'),
  plotlyOutput("plot3D")
)
server = function(input, output) {
  output$plot3D <- renderPlotly({
     req(input$RUN)
     isolate({
       plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec, color = ~am, type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers")
     })
  })
}
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried your code but it still doesn't work. The packages are updated. I am using shiny dashboard... insted of FluidPage i am using FluidRow and tabbox... any ideas? Thank you...

Comment: @alanpter Update your posting, make it a minimal reproducible example and also add your session info.

Comment: Many thanks @lukeA...... Its working now. My CSS file had a bug so didnt get plot.... thanks again....